# RelativeSource works on (nested) sub-property, while ElementName does not

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, elementname

The problem with the code below is: the binding to `SomeClassProp.SubTextProp` doesn't work (the source property is not being set to textbox content), while to `TextProp` it does.

XAML:

```mxml
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        Name="wMain"
        SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=wMain, Path=SomeClassProp.SubTextProp}" Width="120" Height="23" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding ElementName=wMain, Path=TextProp}" Width="120" Height="23" />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

and the code:

```cs
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public SomeClass SomeClassProp { get; set; }
    public string TextProp { get; set; }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        SomeClassProp = new SomeClass();
    }
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public string SubTextProp { get; set; }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious here?

Note that I need this binding to work from target (textbox) to source (class property).

**UPDATE: When I change the binding from `ElementName=wMain` to `RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}` - BOTH bindings work. So the problem is specific to `ElementName` binding property.**

Comment: This ought to work, that why it's called Path. Did you look in the Output Window for binf=ding errors? Verys sure the string was set at all?

Comment: Does it work with a view model?

Comment: No binding errors in the output. The `SubTextProp` remains 'null', while `TextProp` is set to whatever I type into textbox.

Comment: @retailcoder - not sure what you mean by that; I implemented INotifyPropertyChanged on SomeClass, it didn't help - but this is imho irrelevant, as I'm trying to bind from target to source, not the other way round.

Comment: I mean it's easier to bind with the window's `DataContext` than with its own xaml, you would only need the Path part. If you created a class to hold `TextProp` and `SomeClassProp` and assigned an instance of that to the window's `DataContext` instead, you could do {Binding SomeClassProp.SubTextProp}.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, finally, I found the problem!

After adding `diag:PresentationTraceSources.TraceLevel=High` to binding defs (very useful thing btw, in the absence of normal ol' step-by-step debugging), I saw the following in the output:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 108 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930):   At level 0 - for MainWindow.SomeClassProp found accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SomeClassProp)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 104 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930): Replace item at level 0 with MainWindow (hash=47283970), using accessor RuntimePropertyInfo(SomeClassProp)
System.Windows.Data Warning: 101 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930): GetValue at level 0 from MainWindow (hash=47283970) using RuntimePropertyInfo(SomeClassProp): 
System.Windows.Data Warning: 106 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930):   Item at level 1 is null - no accessor
System.Windows.Data Warning: 80 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930): TransferValue - got raw value {DependencyProperty.UnsetValue}
System.Windows.Data Warning: 88 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930): TransferValue - using fallback/default value ''
System.Windows.Data Warning: 89 : BindingExpression (hash=54116930): TransferValue - using final value ''
```

**The problem was in the order of MainWindow initialization!**

So at the moment when the binding was constructed, my level 0 property (`SomeClassProp`) was not yet initialized, which resulted in binding failing completely (without issuing a normal-level binging warning for some reason).

Long story short - moving `SomeClassProp` intitialization before the `InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow` constructor did the trick, binding started to work with `ElementName` too:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    SomeClassProp = new SomeClass();
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

**The answer to question - why it worked using `RelativeSource` property - lies in these lines of the output log**:

```
System.Windows.Data Warning: 66 : BindingExpression (hash=28713467): RelativeSource (FindAncestor) requires tree context
System.Windows.Data Warning: 65 : BindingExpression (hash=28713467): Resolve source deferred
```

Data context initialization with `RelativeSource` requires tree context, and is deferred to some point in time after construction of the `Window` (by that time `SomeClassProperty` was already initialized).